# Server SSL Certification Path Different From Browser Certification Path

Tags: windows, ssl, server

I have recently bought a wildcard SSL certificate from GoDaddy and installed it on a Windows 2003 server. I installed it as follows:

1. Created the CSR and keyed the certificate with it.
2. Finished installing the SSL certificate.
3. Installed the intermediate certs in the intermediate section in MMC.
4. Because the root certificate was not in the trusted certificate section in MMC (because the server is so old) I was getting an error until I downloaded it and installed it in the trusted certificate section.

This is what the path looks like in the server:

[image]

This is what it looks like in the browser (I crossed out the website on the last certificate):

[image]

As you can see, the root certificate is not showing up in the browser. I will also note that when I exported the certificate as a pfx and sent it to our website agency (we only self host some subdomains for the api), the certificate path was working with the root certificate included.

Therefore my hunch is that it's not the certificate. Is the Windows 2003 server being too old messing this up? Please let me know if you need anymore information to be able to help me with this.

Comment: This just means that the browser already trusts the first G2 certificate in the chain, or else that it isn't showing the trusted root. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: This is expected and normal due to certificate cross-signing. The 2003 server can only build a chain due to cross signing. Do you have a problem you are trying to solve? If so, can you re-word the question around the problem?

Comment: Sorry, this issue was causing the site not to function. I was able to fix the problem and commented how down below. Thank you both for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment here since I fixed the issue in case there is anyone one else like me who doesn't know much about SSL certificates and is working with an old server. Once I downloaded the Class 2 Root from GoDaddy directly (I stupidly downloaded it from a third party website before), and I put that in the trust store, everything started to work and the Class 2 certificate disappeared from the chain on the server.